# Style function not working inside Print Row functions

Tags: functional-style, debugging, row

**About**

`Watch[...]` is a helper function for watching a list of variables or other functions inside a `Module[...]` during programming or troubleshooting.

**Goal**
Style `Row[...]` separator so that printed values print apart with distinctively styled separator between items.

**Two Coding Attempts**

For first attempt (`watch1[...]`) separator works but does not style separator. For second attempt (`watch2[...]`) separator is itself styled but kernel complains by reacting with error codes and nothing else works.

```
list = {a, b, c};

Separator = ToString[Style[" | ", Darker[Green], Bold, 12]];
watch1[list_] := 
  Print[Row[
    Table[ToString[list[[i]]] <> Separator, {i, Length[list]}]]];
watch1[list]

watch2[list_] := 
  Print[Row[
    Table[ToString[list[[i]]] <> 
      Style[" | ", Darker[Green], Bold, 12], {i, Length[list]}]]];
watch2[list]
```

**Specific Request**

Please help by correcting code so that it works as cited in **Goal**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
list = {a, b, c};
Separator = Style[" | ", Darker[Green], Bold, 12];
Row[Flatten@ Table[  {ToString[list[[i]]], Separator}, {i, Length[list]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
 Row[Flatten[{ToString[#], Separator} & /@ list]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thanks to Bob Hanlon suggestion, `Riffle` might be better way to go about this so no extra separator at end. The list command above adds `|` at the end, which OP does not want.

```
  result = Row[Riffle[list, Separator]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you for helping me again and again :)

Comment: `watch[list_] := Row@Riffle[list, Separator]; 

watch[list]`

Comment: @Nasser i have one more question: why does it print an extra separator (after last item in list)? how could i stop that behavior?

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you. i shall use your solution as it does not print an extra separator like Nasser's very generous but slightly buggy solution.

Comment: @JulesManson it might be better in this case to use Riffle like Bob suggested if you do not want seperator at end.